# Which case folding types does U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT refer to?

Tags: unicode, icu, case-folding

I'm implementing case folding in a function for JavaScript. I've code generated out of the CaseFolding.txt file the needed JavaScript code.

The documentation for `U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT` says that ICU will use:

> default mappings defined in CaseFolding.txt.

I would like to confirm that using types `C` and `F` are the default option. I know `T` is excluded per the documentation.

> A. To do a simple case folding, use the mappings with status C + S.
>
> B. To do a full case folding, use the mappings with status C + F.
>
> The mappings with status T can be used or omitted depending on the desired case-folding
>      behavior. (The default option is to exclude them.)

Am I selecting the correct values out of `CaseFolding.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether there is access to a buffer: `U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT` refers to the `C` + `S` mappings when using the character functions in `uchar.h` (like [`u_foldCase()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a92925c095397f6af772717acec165d01)), and the `C` + `F` mappings when using the string functions in `ustring.h` (like [`u_strFoldCase()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#ab6709b5a5c1606cf0d3ea24934d9acce)).

In general, you should prefer to use the `C` + `F` mappings whenever possible (e.g., you don't need a 1:1 mapping).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the default. According to section 3.13 ([PDF](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch03.pdf)) of the current Unicode standard (8.0.0), default case folding:

> ... Uses the mappings with the status field value “C” or “F” in the
>   data file CaseFolding.txt in the Unicode Character Database.